# mod_authn_dbd и PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, httpd

Итак имеется модуль *mod_authn_dbd* с настроеным для авторизации *postgresql*, сейчас всё это дело дружно работает на *CentOS 5.2*, a*pache 2.2.3 и apr-1.2.7* . Возникла необходимость проапдейтиться до *CentOS 6.5*, накатил *httpd 2.2.15, apr-1.3.9* перенёс все настройки и данные, но вот незадача, авторизация работает через пень колоду, то пускает, то не пускает. Попробовал через *strace* это дело посмотреть, когда происходит затык выдаёт следуйщее :

> 1786  stat("/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom/server.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=50, ...}) = 0
>   1786  open("/data/servers/www/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 23
>   1786  open("/data/servers/www/soap201505/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   1786  open("/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 23
>   1786  open("/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom/server.php/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
>   1786  stat("/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom/server.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=50, ...}) = 0
>   1786  open("/data/servers/www/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 23
>   1786  open("/data/servers/www/soap201505/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   1786  open("/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 23
>   1786  open("/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom/server.php/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
>   1786  open("/proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled", O_RDONLY) = 24

При этом отличается от нормального входа лишь последней строкой, может кто сталкивался с таким поведением? ;( уже всю голову поломал.

Вот нормальный вовод, при «успешном» логине.

> 1811  stat("/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom/server.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=50, ...}) = 0
>   1811  open("/data/servers/www/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 23
>   1811  open("/data/servers/www/soap201505/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   1811  open("/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 23
>   1811  open("/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom/server.php/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
>   1811  getcwd("/", 4095)                 = 2
>   1811  chdir("/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom") = 0
>   1811  lstat("/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom/server.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=50, ...}) = 0
>   1811  lstat("/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>   1811  lstat("/data/servers/www/soap201505", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>   1811  lstat("/data/servers/www", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>   1811  lstat("/data/servers", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>   1811  lstat("/data", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=14, ...}) = 0
>   1811  readlink("/data", "/cas_dev/data/", 4096) = 14
>   1811  lstat("/cas_dev/data", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>   1811  lstat("/cas_dev", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>   1811  open("/cas_dev/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom/server.php", O_RDONLY) = 24
>   1811  getcwd("/cas_dev/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom", 4096) = 42
>   1811  lstat("/cas_dev/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom/../../soap201106/server.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6172, ...}) = 0
>   1811  lstat("/cas_dev/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom/../../soap201106", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>   1811  lstat("/cas_dev/data/servers/www/soap201505/mtom", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>   1811  lstat("/cas_dev/data/servers/www/soap201505", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>   1811  lstat("/cas_dev/data/servers/www", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>   1811  lstat("/cas_dev/data/servers", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>   1811  open("/cas_dev/data/servers/www/soap201106/server.php", O_RDONLY) = 24
>   1811  open("/usr/share/zoneinfo/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 24
>   1811  stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo//Zulu", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
>   1811  stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo//WET", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1873, ...}) = 0
>   1811  stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo//W-SU", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1448, ...}) = 0
>                                                                             12,1